# Not working .htaccess server error 500

Tags: .htaccess

I get that error when i upload my website to host and try to go on `blabla.com/admin/` but on my xampp everything is working fine...any help? This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```